# Updating HashMap in java

Tags: java, hashmap

Do I need to remove value and then add or can I directly add it in HashMap and it will efficiently updated ?
i.e.

```
HashMap<String, String> person = new HashMap<String, String>();
person.add("name", "John");
```

now which would be a better/efficient way to update above key value :

a)

```
person.remove("name");
person.add("name", "jamy");
```

b)

```
person.add("name", "jamy");
```

or are both just the same ?

This is a very small example. Considering a large HashMap containing other HashMaps, which would be better option and is there any even more efficient way to do so ?

Comment: `HashMap` doesn't even *have* an `add` method. Please do some research before asking questions, and if you want to know how something will behave (the `put` method in this case) you should both try it and read the documentation.

Comment: As Jon stated... your question is answered on the [HashMap Class JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Further, Declare to an Interface, define to a definition. `Map<?,?> map = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 2):

You can put the new value. It will substitute the old one.
From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29):

> > If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

**Note** that the method is `put`, not `add`. **`add` is not a method of `Hashmap`**

Edited: I added the reference link to the documentation as Naman Gala commented.

Answer (score 0):

Use put method, as it will replace value for given key if key exist , otherwise it will create new entry

Answer (score 0):

java.util.HashMap provides put method to add key and object pair in the map. You do not have to remove the object if you want to update the HashMap object. It will return the previous object if there is any object in the map with the same key. Otherwise, it will simply return null. You do not have to remove it every time.  Just use

```
java.util.HashMap.put(key, object);
```